Is there a RHEL compatibility chart for Cassandra?
Could you please let me know if there is any Compatibility chart for Cassandra and RHEL?
More specifically want to know if
Cassandra 3.11 is Compatible with RHEL8* and RHEL9*?
Cassandra 4.1 is Compatible with RHEL7.9?

There is no compatibility chart for platforms because the project doesn't perform that kind of testing.
As a general rule, we recommend running Cassandra 4.1 with newer platform releases. It should work with RHEL 7.9 but that platform is already 4 years old and I suspect hardly any enterprise would use it for newer C* releases.
Similarly, Cassandra 3.11 should work with RHEL 8 and 9 but as always, you should perform your own tests. Also make sure that you check NEWS.txt for any known issues and upgrade recommendations that might be relevant to the platform.
If you are looking for a certain level of assurance and certification, you will need to pay support. It isn't something the community can provide. Cheers!

Thanks a lot, Erick. Actually, We are going to upgrade our existing 3.11 Apache Cassandra to 4.1 and also RHEL7 to RHEL8 and then again to RHEL9. So we are trying to configure which one should be better to perform the first Cassandra upgrade or the RHEL upgrade. For this reason, we are trying to see compatibility perspective both way
